# Find rows in table that containing a value then get a value from those rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem that I have tried to solve without any success. I am not so sharp in Excel.

I have a chart that looks like this (but with a large amount of rows):

1. | X | Text | Text | Value A (Ex. 342) |
2. | - | Text | Text | Value B (Ex. 745) |
3. | - | Text | Text | Value C (Ex. 642) |
4. | X | Text | Text | Value D (Ex. 147) |

Result: 489

As you see in row 1 and 4 they have a "X" mark in their cell A, that means that I want those rows values in cell "D" to add up in the cell "Result".

How can I do this? Appriciate answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use SUMIF or SUMIFS.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I was trying to do that but I cant make it work with multiple rows.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"X")`.